# Building ODK Aggregate for MySQL

Tags: mysql, maven, aggregate, odk

I've been trying to maven build the aggregate-mysql project.
The following is the error shown in terminal on typing:
'mvn install' at the aggregate-mysql directory.

```
  Failed to execute goal on project aggregate-mysql: Could not resolve dependencies for                                      
  project org.opendatakit:aggregate-mysql:war:1.0: The following artifacts could not be
  resolved: org.opendatakit:aggregate-src:jar:latest, org.opendatakit:odk-mysql-it-
  settings:jar:latest, com.google.gdata:gdata-client-1.0:jar:1.47.1,
  com.google.gdata:gdata-client-meta-1.0:jar:1.47.1, com.google.gdata:gdata-core-
  1.0:jar:1.47.1, com.google.gdata:gdata-docs-3.0:jar:1.47.1, com.google.gdata:gdata-
  docs-meta-3.0:jar:1.47.1, com.google.gdata:gdata-maps-2.0:jar:1.47.1, 
  google.gdata:gdata-maps-meta-2.0:jar:1.47.1, com.google.gdata:gdata-media-
  1.0:jar:1.47.1, com.google.gdata:gdata-spreadsheet-3.0:jar:1.47.1, 
  com.google.gdata:gdata-spreadsheet-meta-3.0:jar:1.47.1, com.googlecode.gwt-google-
  maps-v3:gwt-google-maps-v3:jar:snapshot, com.google.gwt.google-apis:gwt-
  visualization:jar:1.1.1, org.javarosa:javarosa-libraries:jar:latest, 
  org.opendatakit:odk-httpclient-gae:jar:1.1, org.opendatakit:odk-tomcatutil:jar:1.0,
  org.openid4java:openid4java-nodeps:jar:0.9.6.662.odk-SNAPSHOT, 
  org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.1.3.odk-SNAPSHOT,  
  org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.1.3.odk-SNAPSHOT, 
  org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:3.1.3.odk-SNAPSHOT,
  org.springframework.security:spring-security-openid:jar:3.1.3.odk-SNAPSHOT, 
  org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.1.3.odk-SNAPSHOT: Failure to 
  find org.opendatakit:aggregate-src:jar:latest in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was 
  cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
  interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
```

I've followed all the process mentioned in configure.txt located at /Users/subashbasnet/opendatakit.aggregate/ and readme.txt located at 
/Users/subashbasnet/opendatakit.aggregate/src/main/libs/readme.txt.
I've also made all the concerned folders read/write enabled. But the error still remains.

Answer (score 1):

The gdata libraries need to be locally installed into Maven (the maven mandubian repository only has up through 1.41.5).

1. Download the 1.47.1 gdata libraries from http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/downloads/list
2. Unzip and in the java/lib directory, execute:

   ```
   mvn install:install-file -Dfile=gdata-core-1.0.jar -DgroupId=com.google.gdata -DartifactId=gdata-core-1.0 -Dversion=1.47.1 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
   mvn install:install-file -Dfile=gdata-client-1.0.jar -DgroupId=com.google.gdata -DartifactId=gdata-client-1.0 -Dversion=1.47.1 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
   mvn install:install-file -Dfile=gdata-client-meta-1.0.jar -DgroupId=com.google.gdata -DartifactId=gdata-client-meta-1.0 -Dversion=1.47.1 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
   mvn install:install-file -Dfile=gdata-docs-3.0.jar -DgroupId=com.google.gdata -DartifactId=gdata-docs-3.0 -Dversion=1.47.1 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
   mvn install:install-file -Dfile=gdata-docs-meta-3.0.jar -DgroupId=com.google.gdata -DartifactId=gdata-docs-meta-3.0 -Dversion=1.47.1 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
   mvn install:install-file -Dfile=gdata-maps-2.0.jar -DgroupId=com.google.gdata -DartifactId=gdata-maps-2.0 -Dversion=1.47.1 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
   mvn install:install-file -Dfile=gdata-maps-meta-2.0.jar -DgroupId=com.google.gdata -DartifactId=gdata-maps-meta-2.0 -Dversion=1.47.1 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
   mvn install:install-file -Dfile=gdata-media-1.0.jar -DgroupId=com.google.gdata -DartifactId=gdata-media-1.0 -Dversion=1.47.1 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
   mvn install:install-file -Dfile=gdata-spreadsheet-3.0.jar -DgroupId=com.google.gdata -DartifactId=gdata-spreadsheet-3.0 -Dversion=1.47.1 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
   mvn install:install-file -Dfile=gdata-spreadsheet-meta-3.0.jar -DgroupId=com.google.gdata -DartifactId=gdata-spreadsheet-meta-3.0 -Dversion=1.47.1 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
   ```